# Deploying a public Google Data Studio connector with the new interface

Tags: looker-studio

I have a working connector that I want to move to another Google account and it looks like I can't make it public on the new account by using this new interface.

I've specified the Test Users I'm using to try and access this connector in the OAuth consent screen, yet I still get an error:

```
The linked connector ID was invalid. Check the connector ID and try again.
```

Is this the correct flow for deploying? before updating the UI, I was using Publish -> Deploy from Manifest...

I'm now trying to use Deploy -> New deployment -> Add on -> Deploy:

[image]

And copying this URL:

[image]

The owner can access the connector, but nobody else can. What to do?

**Later edit:**

Could this be the reason, using a sensitive scope paired with External?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Are there any progress? I have the same issue. If you find the cause of the issue please inform us.

Comment: @OzanBatuhanCeylan - I (temporarily) fixed the issue by going to the Share icon (human torso, head and + sign) and choosing "Anyone on the internet with the link can view", which is kind of stupid to say the least, I imagine anyone can stumble upon my script and see my dedicated endpoints that shouldn't be public. Please let me know if it works for you or if you found some proper solution.